# Can familiars take forms of multiple animals? Like turn from a Raven to a Cat?

Tags: familiars, shapeshifting

Just wondering, can a familiar shape shift into different animals?

Comment: What game (and edition) is this for?

Comment: And have you read the whole feature that grants you a familiar? I’m familiar with familiar features from a few different games and they all explain quite plainly the answer to this question, so some more details about what you have read, and what about it is confusing, might help us resolve your issue more effectively.

Comment: Also, hi, welcome, get comfy! We're asking about the game, because we have loads of different games here we answer questions about and we don't want to assume anything. If it helps we have a [tour], [help] and are happy to answer questions you have in the comments. See you soon!